# Umbraco "GetContentByTag" method cache issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I tried to add tag to document programmatically:

```
var cs = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;

var item = cs.GetById(1227);
item.SetValue("itemTags", "testTagName");

cs.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(item);
cs.RePublishAll();    
umbraco.library.RefreshContent();
```

In another page i need to filter items by tag like this:

```
var filteredItemsByTag = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetContentByTag("testTagName");
```

But this method still does not return an item which was added above. It works only if i "Save and Publish" current item from admin backoffice.

I see in Umbraco.Core that "GetContentByTag " method gets value from RuntimeCacheProvider, which has "Clear()" method, but class is internal, so i can't use it.

Is there any way to get an item?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to call:

```
cs.RePublishAll(); 
umbraco.library.RefreshContent();
```

Use this method for getting nodes by tag - `ApplicationContext.Services.TagService.GetTaggedContentByTag("tag");`

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex, but cache still exists in "GetTaggedContentByTag" method. Only if i set new value for tag, this method returns an item, but it should not as value has been changed

Comment: I've also checked ApplicationContext.Services.ContentService which works correctly and shows correct tag property value